# condicion where con un campo que contiene arrays

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo un campo de una tabla que me almacena a los miembros expositores en un array(que son sus ID):
[image: metadata]
necesito verificar si ya existe algun miembro en algun evento, mi duda es como hago la condicion where con todos los miembros existentes

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y además edita para proveer un [mcve], de otro modo tu pregunta es seguro quede cerrada

Comment: Esa tabla ya estaba asi, o vos la armaste asi? de cualquier manera, que problema tuviste usando un like?

Comment: mi duda es como obtengo a los members para hacer el where, where metadata[members] = 310, si uso un like como obtengo exactamente el objeto de members ? where metadata->members like %$array% ?

Comment: que tipo de dato es en la base de datos? y vuelvo a preguntar esta tabla ya estaba asi o la creaste asi por algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si es indispensable que la tabla esté así, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

Tabla de ejemplo

[image: tabla]

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, '$.members[*]') REGEXP '095|941';
```

La parte de la consulta [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html) busca los números contenidos en members y los deja así
["535", "451", "465"], luego simplemente buscas los números que necesites. Un like haría lo mismo, simplemente acá separa los id de members, sería cuestión de mirar cuál es más rápido y eficiente.

Comment: perfecto es lo que estaba buscando